# MySQL group by kills the query performance

Tags: mysql, innodb

I have MySQL query currently selecting and joining 13 tables and finally grouping ~60k rows. The query without grouping takes ~0ms but with grouping the query time increases to ~1.7sec. The field, which is used for grouping is primary field and is indexed. Where could be the issue?

I know group by without aggregate is considered invalid query and bad practise but I need distinct base table rows and can not use DISTINCT syntax.

The query itself looks like this:

```
SELECT `table_a`.*
FROM   `table_a` 
       LEFT JOIN `table_b` 
              ON `table_b`.`invoice` = `table_a`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `table_c` AS `r1` 
              ON `r1`.`invoice_1` = `table_a`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `table_c` AS `r2` 
              ON `r2`.`invoice_2` = `table_a`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `table_a` AS `i1` 
              ON `i1`.`id` = `r1`.`invoice_2` 
       LEFT JOIN `table_a` AS `i2` 
              ON `i2`.`id` = `r2`.`invoice_1` 
       JOIN `table_d` AS `_u0` 
         ON `_u0`.`id` = 1 
       LEFT JOIN `table_e` AS `_ug0` 
              ON `_ug0`.`user` = `_u0`.`id` 
       JOIN `table_f` AS `_p0` 
         ON ( `_p0`.`enabled` = 1 
              AND ( ( `_p0`.`role` < 2 
                      AND `_p0`.`who` IS NULL ) 
                     OR ( `_p0`.`role` = 2 
                          AND ( `_p0`.`who` = '0' 
                                 OR `_p0`.`who` = `_u0`.`id` ) ) 
                     OR ( `_p0`.`role` = 3 
                          AND ( `_p0`.`who` = '0' 
                                 OR `_p0`.`who` = `_ug0`.`group` ) ) ) ) 
            AND ( `_p0`.`action` = '*' 
                   OR `_p0`.`action` = 'read' ) 
            AND ( `_p0`.`related_table` = '*' 
                   OR `_p0`.`related_table` = 'table_name' ) 
       JOIN `table_a` AS `_e0` 
         ON ( ( `_p0`.`related_id` = 0 
                 OR `_p0`.`related_id` = `_e0`.`id` 
                 OR `_p0`.`related_user` = `_e0`.`user` 
                 OR `_p0`.`related_group` = `_e0`.`group` ) 
               OR ( `_p0`.`role` = 0 
                    AND `_e0`.`user` = `_u0`.`id` ) 
               OR ( `_p0`.`role` = 1 
                    AND `_e0`.`group` = `_ug0`.`group` ) ) 
            AND `_e0`.`id` = `table_a`.`id` 
       JOIN `table_d` AS `_u1` 
         ON `_u1`.`id` = 1 
       LEFT JOIN `table_e` AS `_ug1` 
              ON `_ug1`.`user` = `_u1`.`id` 
       JOIN `table_f` AS `_p1` 
         ON ( `_p1`.`enabled` = 1 
              AND ( ( `_p1`.`role` < 2 
                      AND `_p1`.`who` IS NULL ) 
                     OR ( `_p1`.`role` = 2 
                          AND ( `_p1`.`who` = '0' 
                                 OR `_p1`.`who` = `_u1`.`id` ) ) 
                     OR ( `_p1`.`role` = 3 
                          AND ( `_p1`.`who` = '0' 
                                 OR `_p1`.`who` = `_ug1`.`group` ) ) ) ) 
            AND ( `_p1`.`action` = '*' 
                   OR `_p1`.`action` = 'read' ) 
            AND ( `_p1`.`related_table` = '*' 
                   OR `_p1`.`related_table` = 'table_name' ) 
       JOIN `table_g` AS `_e1` 
         ON ( ( `_p1`.`related_id` = 0 
                 OR `_p1`.`related_id` = `_e1`.`id` 
                 OR `_p1`.`related_user` = `_e1`.`user` 
                 OR `_p1`.`related_group` = `_e1`.`group` ) 
               OR ( `_p1`.`role` = 0 
                    AND `_e1`.`user` = `_u1`.`id` ) 
               OR ( `_p1`.`role` = 1 
                    AND `_e1`.`group` = `_ug1`.`group` ) ) 
            AND `_e1`.`id` = `table_a`.`company` 
WHERE  `table_a`.`date_deleted` IS NULL 
       AND `table_a`.`company` = 4
       AND `table_a`.`type` = 1
       AND `table_a`.`date_composed` >= '2016-05-04 14:43:55' 
GROUP BY `table_a`.`id`
```

Comment: based on that query, sizing, and a dozen tables, I would say 1.7s is pretty darn good

Comment: You could also run an explain on your query to get an idea of where the actual 'bottlenecks' are.

Comment: @jeff I actually did that but I have no previous experience with it so its hard to act upon it, I copied it here: https://jsfiddle.net/x1q02108/ , any suggestions?

Comment: @Drew not fast enough for me - any suggestions to make it faster? Tried sub queries but the gain was trivial

Comment: Easy for me to say but redesign your logic and schema. Know that you have a miserable mess for the db engine to figure out which has little to do with indexes and explain

Answer (score 0):

The `ORs` kill performance.

This composite index may help:  `INDEX(company, type, date_deleted, date_composed)`.

`LEFT JOIN table_b ON table_b.invoice = table_a.id` seems to do absolutely nothing other than slow down the processing.  No fields of `table_b` are used or `SELECTed`.  Since it is a `LEFT` join, it does not limit the output.  Etc.  Get rid if it, or justify it.

Ditto for other joins.

What happens with `JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:  First, all the joins are performed; this explodes the number of rows in the intermediate 'table'.  Then the `GROUP BY` implodes the set of rows.

One technique for avoiding this explode-implode sluggishness is to do

```
SELECT ...,
    ( SELECT ... ) AS ...,
    ...
```

instead of a `JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN`.  However, that works only if there is zero or one row in the subquery.  Usually this is beneficial when an aggregate (such as `SUM`) can be moved into the subquery.

For further discussion, please include `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: You mean ORs kill the performance in collaboration with grouping? Because only selecting and joining rows is lighting fast.I have tried the composite index, no major effect tho. If some tables may seem not to be used, they actually sometimes are - my current ORM have some limitations on selecting tables that are actually used. I have tried with sub queries, the time did not improve, rather increased. My sub queries always return more than one rows. Which table structure are you interested in - all 13 tables? I can assure all the fields have correct indexes and field types - tho you never know.

Comment: `x=1 OR y=2` cannot use any kind of index; hence it is inefficient for filtering (`WHERE`).

Comment: but how am I not feeling that inefficiency without grouping?

Comment: "0ms" usually implies that the Query cache is enabled and the query was recently run.  Run again with an added flag:  `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...`

Comment: good idea, but I still get acceptable 15 - 30ms when I add SQL_NO_CACHE

Comment: I recommend using that flag when timing queries.  It bypasses the query cache, which often gives an unrealistic "0ms".  So, if you are getting 30ms with the flag, is that good enough?  If so, remove the flag; then you will get either 30 or 0, depending on whether the QC is useful.

Comment: yes it is good enough for me but that doesn't help on grouping, which still gives me ~2 sec